# Enumerating Wifi devices on a network

Tags: wifi, mobile-devices, security

I'm trying to monitor what devices are active in a Wifi network. This is specifically about mobile phones that connect to a Wifi-Router. While I do know how to enumerate Wifi networks in reach I would also like to enumerate devices that are connected to those networks. I do not have access to the routers, or to be precise, they run software that cannot be used to monitor them, but I do have a Notebook sitting next to the router.

Would something like `airodump` allow me to periodically enumerate the devices and write them to a file?

Comment: Open the interface on the router, and look at the connection section for Wifi.

Comment: At the very leats, if this is a full wifi network, the content of your ARP table after abroadcast ping may help ?

Comment: There are 3rd party tools like: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html that basically just do what @Kwaio is referring to.  But it is basic home use crap.  Most biz wifi routers/controllers can give you this info. What types of routers?  Why don't you have access to them?

Answer (score 1):

What OS is the notebook running? [Kismet](http://kismetwireless.net/) was written with this task in mind and is a standard package on most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You could cron a script that redirects the output of `nmap` to a file, and parse that file however you want.